# Ethernet communication timeout. ARP?

Tags: udp, timeout, freeze, ethernet, arp

I am working on a project where the software on the Win10 PC sends UDP/IP messages to a MCU board and the MCU replies with data (ping-pong). I see the same on Arduino and in this case Microchip PIC32MZ boards.

Everything works fine until I disconnect the MCU (or stop it in its debugger). The PC keeps sending messages and if I connect/resume the MCU within about 20 seconds, the communication just resumes. After that the PC stop putting the pings on the Ethernet line even when the MCU is connected/resumed. The PC program still thinks they are sent but there are no LED flashing and no messages in WireShark. In fact it takes exactly one minute and then Windows sends an ARP and the communication resumes.

I have tried to use "SendARP" on the PC side in this dead period to wake up the communication, but the ARP doesn't make it to the Ethernet line either.

Is there some way to wake it up within this minute?

Is it possible to change some setting to make the period shorter?

Thanks

Comment: You should try `arp -a` while pings don't work to see what shows up in the ARP table - possibly Win10 caches failed ARPs. If that is the case you could use `arp -d *` to clear the ARP table.